# Limit of a decreasing sequence of outer measures is an outer measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The problem given to me on my homework is:

> Prove that the limit of a decreasing family of outer measures is an outer measure.

Doing out the "obvious" approach, we quickly reach the problem of wanting to say that
$$\lim_{j\to\infty}\;\mu_j^*\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right)\leq\lim_{j\to\infty}\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\;\mu_j^*(A_i)\right)\underbrace{\leq}_{\text{PROBLEM}}\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left(\lim_{j\to\infty}\;\mu_j^*(A_i)\right)$$
The problem, as I see it, is that [Fatou's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%E2%80%99s_lemma) has the inequality going the opposite way of what we want here (by the way, this course hasn't actually gotten to integration yet).

In fact, I think the claim is false, because I can imagine very well having the following scenario:

- $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^\infty\subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ is a family of subsets of $X$ (disjoint, probably)
- $\mu_j^*:\mathcal{P}(X)\to[0,\infty]$ are decreasing family of outer measures on $X$ with the property that
  $$\mu_j^*(A_i)=\begin{cases}1\text{ if }j\leq i\\ 0\text{ if }j>i \end{cases}$$
  (This certainly would not be in conflict with the assumption that the $\mu_j^*$ are decreasing, i.e. that $\mu_j^*(A)\geq\mu_{j+1}^*(A)$ for all $j\in\mathbb{N}$ and $A\subseteq X$.)

Letting $\mu^*:\mathcal{P}(X)\to[0,\infty]$ be defined by $\mu^*(A)=\lim_{j\to\infty}\mu_j^*(A)$, we conclude immediately that $\mu^*(\varnothing)=0$ and that $\mu^*(A)\leq\mu^*(B)$ when $A\subseteq B$, but we then have that
$$\mu^*\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right)=\lim_{j\to\infty}\;\mu_j^*\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right)\geq\lim_{j\to\infty}\;\mu_j^*(A_j)=\lim_{j\to\infty}\;1=1$$
while
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\;\mu^*(A_i)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left(\lim_{j\to\infty}\;\mu_j^*(A_i)\right)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left(\lim_{j\to\infty}\;\;{1\text{ if }j\leq i\atop 0\text{ if }j>i}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\;0=0 $$
so that 
$$\mu^*\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right)\not\leq\sum_{i=1}^\infty\;\mu^*(A_i)$$
and therefore $\mu^*$ is not an outer measure.

So, giving as little away as possible (as this is a homework question), is the scenario I proposed above impossible? I tried to construct examples with $X=\mathbb{N}$ and the value of $\mu_j^*(A)$ depending on whether $A\cap\{1,\ldots,j\}=\varnothing$, but that didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Zev, I think I see it now.

We define an outer measure on a set $X$ to be a function $\mu*:\mathcal{P}(X)\to[0,\infty]$, as you have mentioned. But in your counter-example, you assumed that the $A_i$ were disjoint to preserve countable additivity (at least, when I first heard the question, I thought that their disjoint-ness allowed us to maintain countable additivity.).

I am almost certain that this is not, in fact, an outer measure now, because I do not think the sets can be enumerated (if they can be) in such a way to preserve additivity despite the fact that they are not actually disjoint.

Comment: @mixedmath: But outer measures need only be countably *subadditive*; I was only proposing the $A_i$ be disjoint because it seems like it'd be easier to construct a counterexample when that's the case. (By the way, the original counterexample I'd proposed failed because the $\mu_j^*$ weren't monotonic; taking a set disjoint from $\{1,\ldots,j\}$ and adding in something from $\{1,\ldots,j\}$ decreased its $\mu_j^*$-measure.)

Comment: Aha, of course. How quick of me. And here, I was so pleased that it was suddenly so obvious. Hmm.

Comment: Well, the exchange of limit and sum would be okay for an [increasing sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Convergence_of_a_monotone_series) of measures anyway...

Comment: If you take $\mu^*_j$ to be equal to zero measure on the integers up to $j$ and equal to counting measure elsewhere, I think that's your counterexample. On the other hand, could it be that the outer measures are meant to be finite?

Comment: @Niels: Thanks, that works! I'll bring it up to the teacher. If you'd like to post that as an answer, I'll accept it, or I can post my write-up of it as a Community Wiki answer.

Comment: Here's a positive variant of the result you ask about:

1. Let $\varphi: \mathcal{P}(X) \to [0,\infty]$ be *any* function such that $\varphi(\emptyset) = 0$. Put
$$\mu_{\varphi}^{\ast}(A) = \inf{\left\{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\varphi(A_n)\,:\,A \subset \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n\right\}}$$
then $\mu_{\varphi}^{\ast}$ is an outer measure.
2. If $\{\mu_{j}^{\ast}\}_{j \in J}$ is an arbitrary family of outer measures, let $\varphi(A) = \inf_{j \in J} \mu_{j}^{\ast}(A)$. Then $\mu_{\varphi}^{\ast}$ is the largest outer measure $\mu^{\ast}$ satisfying $\mu^{\ast} \leq \mu_{j}^{\ast}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\gamma$ be the counting measure on the positive integers. Define 
$\mu^*_j(A) = \gamma( \{ x \in A | x \ge j \})$.
That this sequence is decreasing follows from the monotonicity of $\gamma$.
Since every finite set is bounded, its measure converges to 0 as $j \to \infty$.
On the other hand, the measure of infinite sets is infinite for all $j$.
This contradicts countable subadditivity of the limit.

I have not checked, but it seems likely that the exercise can be fixed by substituting "finite outer measure" for "outer measure".